# Как добавить значение счётчика в localStorage в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localstorage

```
Я создаю конструктор Бургера. Отрендерила ингредиенты через map. Теперь хочу чтобы при переключении вкладок (использую реакт роутер) значение счётчика на каждом элементе сохранялось.
Мой код работает НО, изменяет значение на всех ингредиентах одновременно. Что я делаю не так? Это мой первый проект на реакт.

Разметка:
return (
      <div className="ingredients">
        <div className="ingr-card">
            <div className="image-ingr">
              <img src={image} alt="cotlet" /> 
            </div>
            <div className="name-ingr">
              <p>{name}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="counter">
              <button disabled={!count} onClick={minus}>-</button>
              <p>{count}</p>
              <button disabled={count>=3} onClick={plus}>+</button>
            </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  );
}


Добавляю в localStorage:
const getFromStorage = () => { // получить значение из localStorage
    const storage = window.localStorage.getItem('storageCountValue');
    return storage !== null ? parseInt(storage) : 0;
    };
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(getFromStorage);
    useEffect(
        () => window.localStorage.setItem('storageCountValue', count),
        [count]
    );



  const plus = () => {
    setCount(count => count + 1); }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что в localStorage, каждый ингредиент у вас присваивается к одному и тому же ключу `storageCountValue`.
Существует множество решений такой проблемы.

Вот моё предложение. Создать ключ с названием `burgerSettings` и в нём хранить данные такого вида(в формате JSON):

```
{
  cutlet:number,
  mayo:number,
  onion:number,
  tomato:number,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Я создала ключ 
  let burgerSetting = {"Cutlet":0, "Mayo":0, "Onion":0, "Tomato":0, "Cucumber":0, "Cheese":0, "Salad":0};
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(burgerSetting[name]);
  Но я теперь совершенно запуталась с кодом в localStorage

Comment: @YuliiaKulachko `JSON.parse` / `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @YuliiaKulachko, это вы создали не ключ, а состояние. Ключ имеется ввиду localStorage. Вот вам статейка https://myrusakov.ru/javascript-save-array-or-object-localstorage.html . Пожалуйста прочитайте полностью, она не длинная.